# get_users by role returns all users

Tags: templates, users

I am trying to fetch all users with a specific role eg `blogger` and `blogger_pro`
but my code just returns all users rather than those with that specific role. Hope someone can tell me whats wrong?

The above roles have been added using the plugin `User Role Editor`

Function:

```
function get_role_specific_users($role){
    $args = array(
        'role'    => $role,
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    );
    return get_users( $args );
}
```

And then calling it like this:

```
$pro_authors = get_role_specific_users('blogger_pro');
$authors = get_role_specific_users('blogger');
```

But both arrays just contains all users rather than those with that role :/

Comment: May be this will help you as this question already answered .
[ClickHere](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219686/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-users-by-their-role)

Comment: That was the first thing i tried, but the examples there return all users to me, rather than role specific users :/